# Apparently good yagnya by Daksha

Tags: yajna, daksha

The author of popular *Lingashtakam* stotram extolled Shiva as destroyer of Yagnya conducted by Daksha (father in-law)  describing it as *suyagna* that is contradiction in its very terms.

Can we explain how the Supreme power viewed the act to be right and justifiable to all? Non-invitation to a function may appear to be a minor insult but what *adharma* background proved cause for his destructive revenge?

Comment: Daksha thought he had daksha (strength) to create the whole world but forgot that daksha was none other than his daughter Dakshayani (Goddess who is other half of Shiva). When Daksha insulted Shiva, his Shakti (daksha) also got insulted and left Daksha.

Comment: Su might mean well organized in Suyagnya and not good

Comment: My source is Quora etc, but question is elsewhere so shall edit it.

Comment: This question seems motivated.  Rama went and killed Ravana for the mere ABDUCTION of his wife - Krishna killed someone just for name-calling.  The provocation seems big here and at any rate Daksha was restored to life.  The reason was not non-invitation - its a gross falsehood. Don't see the point of this question.

Comment: Please elucidate what the big provocation is.Reviving Daksha happened much after events  that culminated in his  actual killing. I have no motivation whatever.

Comment: Rudra becomes angry after his wife self immolates in the yagnya that itself is great provacation and offence.. The whole yagnya is lesson to those who ignore shiva in worship or who disrepect other dieties eventhough they extoll vishnu in that yagnya Each deities need to be invoked according to status(devata tartamya) in yagnya and respected that is the message.. otherwise yagnya will give bad and opposite results that is the message..